# what log value to use for Kullback leibler divergence implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, nlp

I have done a method to implement the Kullback-leibler divergence in java.  I have used   the log with base 2 value and i am not sure whether i have used it right or i should used log base 10 value. I am using this method to measure the divergence between two text units(each of different length).

My problem is i don't get the desired divergence measure .

for example for two text units namely => "Free Ringtones" and the second one "Free Ringtones for your Mobile Phone from PremieRingtones.com"

I should get a divergence of 0.25(as of my project references) but i get a divergence of 2.0 if i use log base2 and 1.38 for log base10.

Also i am unaware of what value to substitute instead of zero value for demnominator.Plz help in giving clear explaination with some examples if possible and even some links to where i can get details.

This is My code snippet:

```
public Double calculateKLD(List<String> values,List<String> value2)   
{  

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  
    Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  
    for (String sequence : values)  
    {  
        if (!map.containsKey(sequence))  
        {  
            map.put(sequence, 0);
        }
        map.put(sequence, map.get(sequence) + 1);
    }

    for (String sequence : value2)  
    {  
        if (!map2.containsKey(sequence)) {
            map2.put(sequence, 0);
        }
        map2.put(sequence, map2.get(sequence) + 1);
    }

    Double result = 0.0;
    Double frequency2=0.0;
    for (String sequence : map.keySet())  
    {

        Double frequency1 = (double) map.get(sequence) / values.size();
        System.out.println("Freuency1 "+frequency1.toString());
        if(map2.containsKey(sequence))
        {

            frequency2 = (double) map2.get(sequence) / value2.size();                
        }
        result += frequency1 * (Math.log(frequency1/frequency2) / Math.log(2));         
    }  
    return result/2.4;  
}
```

My Input is like this

**First text unit**

```
   list.add("Free");list.add("Ringtones");
```

**Second text unit**

```
      list2.add("Free");list2.add("Ringtones");list2.add("for");list2.add("your");list2.add("Mobiile");list2.add("Phone");list2.add("from");list2.add("PremieRingtones.com");
```

Calling function

```
   calculateKLD(list, list2)
```

Comment: Using different logarithms will yield proportional values. With log2, we say divergence is expressed in **bits**, with natural log in **nats** and with log10, well, I don't know about any terminology, but you usually end with **decibels** after multiplying by 10. They are bona fide units, with a constant conversion factor between them, like meters and miles, pounds and metric tons, etc.

Comment: well if you use log256, you'll get 0.25.  It looks like your computation is correct.  when i manually calculate it, i get 2.0.  If you switch it around and do D_KL(Q||P), I get -0.5.

Comment: Why do you write "`map.put(sequence, 0);`" instead of "`map.put(sequence, 1);`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess, you probably want to use log base e (i.e. natural logarithm). Since K-L divergence is a statistical measure, odds are that it's defined in terms of natural logarithms.

Comment: People doing information theory use base 2 log, this yields results with an interpretation in terms of **bits**.